# Victim of Muse, new to programming, don't even know how to describe what I am trying to do in computer or programming terms

Tags: php, css, sql, html

thanks in advance...
I am brand spanking new to programming, trying to get my first, very simple, website up off the ground. I understand how to do all the HTML associated with what I am doing (I think anyway), but I have a specific need and I don't even know how to describe it without several sentences...here goes...

I need something similar to what online petition sites use. I need something that lets users input their name, which will then be added to a list of names they see above. Ideally, I would like to have some names already entered in the box before the first user ever comes across the page. I don't care about e-mail confirmation or collecting their e-mail, I just simply want the user to be able to input a name and have it show up on the site as soon as they hit the send button.

I am a fairly quick learner, so if anybody could point me in the right direction, any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to take some PHP tutorials as this would be PHP 101. Go to codecademy.com

Comment: Sounds like a good old fashioned guest book.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST['name'] ) && $_POST['name'] != '' );
    {
            echo $_POST['name'] . '<br>';
    }
?>
<form method="post">
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="type name" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This code has zero validation, so a malicious user could input anything. Read up on https://phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html